# How does this substitution work, x=arctan(u)?

Tags: integration

I was trying to solve an integral and got the following results:

$$
\int \frac{1}{sin\left(2x\right)}dx=\int \frac{1}{2sin\left(x\right)cos\left(x\right)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{sinx}{sin^2\left(x\right)cos\left(x\right)}dx=
$$
$$
u=cos(x), du=-sin(x)dx
$$
$$
sin^2x=1-cos^2x
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u\left(1-u^2\right)}du=-\frac{1}{2}\int \:\frac{1}{-u\left(u+1\right)\left(u-1\right)}du=
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left[-\int \frac{1}{u}du+\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u+1}du+\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u-1}du\right]=
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\left|\cos x\right|\right)+\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\left|\cos x+1\right|\right)+\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\left|\cos x-1\right|\right)
$$
The textbook gave me a different solution method, which is also understandable, using a similar technique:
$$
\int \frac{sin\left(2x\right)}{1-cos^2\left(2x\right)}dx=
$$
$$
y=cos(2x), dy=-2sin(2x)dx
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dy}{y^2-1}=
$$
$$
\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{1}{y-1}-\frac{1}{y+1}dy=
$$
$$
\frac{1}{4}\ln \left|\frac{\cos \left(2x\right)-1}{\cos \left(2x\right)+1}\right|
$$
However, when tried to solve with symbolab it turned out disgustingly simple:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{sin\left(2x\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\:\int \:\frac{1}{\cos \:\left(x\right)\sin \:\left(x\right)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\:\int \:\frac{\sec \:\left(x\right)}{\sin \:\left(x\right)}dx=
$$
$$
x=arctan(u)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{u}du=\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|u\right|=\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|\tan \left(x\right)\right|
$$
And I really can't understand this substitution part.
Can someone explain how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally rather write it as $u = \tan{x}$, but: divide the numerator and denominator by $ \cos{x} $ (or multiply by $\sec{x}$ ) to get
$$ \int \frac{\sec^2{x}}{\tan{x}} \, dx $$
from which it is now apparent.

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks for highlighting the missing step, now it totally makes sense.